# My APK crashes on Android build with buildozer

Tags: android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer, p4a

I developed my application with kivy and kivymd. And when I turned it into .apk it crashes suddenly after asking for permissions without any other error than

```
[WARNING] [Base] Unknown <android> provider.
```

I have done several research especially on this site but also on github and none could solve my problem.
I also want to point out that I compile in a virtual machine running Debian 11. And all this is done in a virtual environment python.
The app use kivy, kivymd , matplotlib and some others libs.
Here is the requirements line of the .spec file

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==1.1.1,matplotlib,requests,urllib3,pillow,https://github.com/kivy-garden/graph/archive/master.zip,contourpy, cycler, fonttools, importlib-resources, kiwisolver, numpy, packaging,pyparsing, python-dateutil,chardet
```

Thanks you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an another version of kivymd. Try `kivymd==1.0.2` in the requirements section. If this doesn't work there's something other not working.